# CSS 'fragmenter' or unconsolidator?

Tags: css

Is there a tool to convert something like

font:bold 1.9em "Book Antiqua",Verdana,Tahoma,"Trebuchet MS",sans-serif;

to

font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.9em;
font-family: "Book Antiqua",Verdana,Tahoma,"Trebuchet MS",sans-serif

in CSS files?

BTW, I am not sure what to call this process.

Comment: Just for curiosity, what would you need to do this for?

Comment: Because I have css files and the same font family is mentioned in many selectors which is redundant and a waste of space and bandwidth. 
If the font-family is in its own separate attribute, I can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Elbow grease, unfortunately.

More helpfully, I suppose that if your strings are always going to be in the same format (font weight first, size next, fonts 3rd, etc) it's possible that you could write a helper function to parse those strings, but it will be intense...

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome (or this would work with firebug as well) you can bring up the CSS properties for an element in the developer window (ctrl-shift-J), choose the elements tab and click on an element.

Even if the CSS applied to the element is short-form the browser will expand that out to long-form and you can copy/paste right from the "Computed Style" sidebar.

[Chrome Dev CSS http://img2.imageshack.us/img2/2649/chromedevcss.png](http://img2.imageshack.us/img2/2649/chromedevcss.png)

Comment: I need to modify it in the css files.

Comment: Copy it out of the sidebar and paste it into your CSS file in its expanded form.